# how to add gem by default

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to ruby and gem. I recently cross compiled ruby and now trying to launch an gem on my OS.

The gem depends on 12 other gems. Is there a way I can compile those gems as default gems with ruby so that I can directly launch my gem on OS?

Appreciate any help and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gem install YOUR_GEM_NAME
```

This will download and install the gem on our local machine. It should also download any dependencies.

Comment: The target machine would be standalone (not internet access). Also no make since some gems look for make on "gem install"

 I want to precompile those so that only single install gem install would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the gems you want to install don't depend on C extensions, then install ruby on a similar architecture that has internet access, install the gems there, the gems usually go to the `GEM_HOME` directory e.g `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247`, upon installing ruby in the system that does not have internet access, all you need to do is copy the `GEM_HOME` directory, and your `gem` should be available directly.